# In what order would you recommend when reading the books of the minor prophets for better understanding?

Tags: bible, chronology

I found it a bit difficult to follow the storyline the books of the minor prophet presented even though I read them chronologically. I was wondering if there was a particular order they should be read for better understanding.

Comment: Welcome to CSE! Unfortunately, this site is not one where you can ask opinion based questions. Questions should be directed at specific denominations or asking for something like the biblical basis for a doctrine. See how we are [different than other sites](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) here, and take the site [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @LukeHill I don't see why someone cannot be given some helpful information. We don't have to put the rules of the site above kindness to strangers, do we ?

Comment: @NigelJ that’s honestly surprising to hear you say :) but yea I’m not voting to close or flagging. I just want the new person to read our tour and site info so they won’t get closed in the future.

Comment: @NigelJ  -- I  agree with  with you. The ritual purity of the site is not polluted by questions such as this ;-) ... and it looks like this new user was scared off, regardless of Luke's intent.

Answer (score 3):

I find it best to match the prophetic books with the history as given in Kings and Chronicles.

J N Darby has a helpful chronological table in the preface to his translation of the bible (though, with genuine grief, I have to say that I cannot recommend his translation as it is not clear to me - from his prefaces - what Greek text he is translating) :

Zechariah . . . . . .  King Uzziah of Judah . . . . . . .Zachariah/Shalum of Israel

Isaiah/Micah . . . . . King Jotham/Ahaz of Judah . . . . King Hoshea of Israel

Nahum . . . . . . . .. King Hezekiah of Judah . . . . .  **(Captivity of Israel)**

Joel . . . . . . . . . King Manasseh of Judah

Jeremiah . . . . . . . King Josiah of Judah

**Captivity of Judah**

Habakkuk . . . . . . . King Jehoahaz of Judah

Zephaniah . . . . . . .King Jehoiakim of Judah

Ezekiel . . . . . . .. King Jehoiachin/'Jeconiah'

Daniel . . . . . . ... Nebuchadnezzar/Cyrus/Carius

Obadiah . . . . . . . .Zedekiah

**Governors in Jerusalem after Return from Captivity**

Haggai . . . . . . . . Zerubbabel

Zechariah . . . . . . .Ezra

Malachi . . . . . . . . Nehemiah

J N Darby also has the timing of the Kings and their length of reign, for example Jotham (of Judah) 16 years from 758 B.C.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, I haven’t seen this idea before!